# ssh authentication fails after ssh-agent terminates

Tags: ssh, archlinux

Backstory: currently running Arch Linux and attempting to authenticate into Github using SSH keys. I have openssh 7.1p1-1 installed as well as git 2.6.4-1.

Problem: After the ssh-agent terminates (system reboot or shell closure), I get the "Permission Denied (publickey)" message when attempting to connect to git using:

```
    ssh -vT git@github.com
```

[image: Console output of SSH]

Any ideas as to why my identity does not persist? Do I have to add anything special to the ~/.ssh/config or /etc/ssh/ssh_config files?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `ssh-agent` is gone, `ssh` is no longer aware that `id_github` exists, so it never tries authenticating with that key. If you want to force `ssh` to always use that key for `github.com`, you can add this to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_github
    User git # Handy addition so you can skip the username part in Github URLs
```

Comment: My question of why the SSH key does not persist was answered here. But it seems that using this solution won't help when attempting to clone from github. So after more research, I have enabled a keyring and added my id_github ssh key to it. Thanks for your help!